# Plist file path error?

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, plist

I am trying to save an NSMutableArray containing text to a plist file using this code:

```
- (IBAction)saveDoc:(id)sender
{
NSString *typedText = typingArea.text;
NSMutableArray *totalFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:typedText, nil];
NSLog(@"Created: %@", totalFiles);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedFiles.plist"];
NSLog(@"Found Path: %@", path);
//[totalFiles addObject:typedText];

[totalFiles writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"File Written: %@  to: %@", totalFiles, path);
[totalFiles release];
NSLog(@"Released: %@", totalFiles);
}
```

All of the NSLogs return appropriate values as expected.  I use this code to crate a new NSMutableArray with the contents of the plist:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"savedFiles" ofType:@"plist"];
NSLog(@"Got Path: %@", file);
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSLog(@"Loaded Array into new array: %@", array);





//UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"fdsfasdf" message:[dic objectForKey:@"item1"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ldfghjfd" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
//[alert show];



[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

The NSLogs in this code come back with a slightly different path than the first one returned with.  It also said the array is (null)

How should I load the contents from a plist file?

Thanks in advance,

Tate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initialising your array first:

`array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];`

Comment: Thanks!  Itt displays the file!  Now how do I get it to display multiple files?  For example: if the user creates a file then saves it, it shows up in the tableview.  Then if the user creates another file and saves it, I want it to add another cell to the tableview, not overwrite and replace the old one, if you know what I'm saying.  Thanks!  Tate